# I need to return standard html/JSON Status codes from asp SOAP WebService

Tags: c#, android, json, web-services, soap

We work with a c# SOAP WebService and we use this WebService 
from an ASP.NET Web Application.

The WebService Class has these Compiler Tags:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://myWebService/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
```

Since it was requested that the WebService can also communicate with JSON clients we added this Compiler Tag:

```
[ScriptService]
```

Methods are tagged with

```
[WebMethod] 
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

It all works fine with SOAP clients and with JSON clients.

But there is an Issue with Exceptions:

The SOAP Client can deal with the SoapExceptions of the WebService Methods.

The JSON Clients (javaScript and Android) only get the Status
500 and some Error Message - they don't get an Exception Object for any reason I don't know.

The Android Developer wants to receive Standard Status Codes from the WebService in case something went wrong - i.e. codes like 
404, 403 ... because he cannot get an Error Object from the WebService Method.

Important Note: 
I did already turn the Custom Error to "OFF" in the web.config file 
because It would be inefficient to always send "Internal Server Error" in any occurrence of an Exception.

So my question is:
How can I achieve this:

to throw an Exception in the WebService that will be serialized to the JSON client with the Error-Code "404" and with some individual Error Message.